# Rails Queue Across All Active Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, api, queue, throttling

Rephrasing completely my question.

I am the consumer of APIs that are throttled and need to make sure I throttle my calls which could come from many different sources. In effect I need to do the reverse of http://martinciu.com/2011/08/how-to-add-api-throttle-to-your-rails-app.html

Can I either have a truly global variable like below that could be accessible from each user connecting session? or is there a GEM already that will help me queue up requests according to API requirements of lets say max 4 API calls per second

Idea of a app wide queue variable:

```
req_queue = { 
:api_name1 => [ '2014/11/26 13:00:00', '2014/11/26 13:00:01', '2014/11/26 13:00:01'],
:api_name2 => [ '2014/11/26 13:00:01', '2014/11/26 13:00:01', '2014/11/26 13:00:01'],
etc
}
```

My thinking is to add a timestamp for each request and each time the expired ones will get purged by the next completed API call and/or next incoming API call as appropriate.

Comment: Just to add.. I think I can figure out the queuing part logic and coding it manually myself but I need a variable that will allow me to store the queue and retrieve it from any User executions no matter what request they belong to.. hope im clear enough... otherwise I may need to use [link](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/background-jobs-in-ruby-on-rails/) for that? hope its simpler with a shared session of some sort like ENV variables...?